# SAP HANA: how to catch SQL exception in procedure thrown by nested procedure?

Tags: sql, hana

I have a SQL procedure which throws an exception in particular cases:

```
SIGNAL EMPTY_REQ_ATTR SET message_text = 'my mega error message';
```

This procedure has an exit handler:

```
DECLARE EMPTY_REQ_ATTR CONDITION;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR EMPTY_REQ_ATTR RESIGNAL EMPTY_REQ_ATTR;
```

This SQL procedure is called in another SQL procedure where I try to catch this exception like this:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    errors = SELECT 400 AS http_code, ::SQL_ERROR_MESSAGE AS message FROM dummy;
END;
```

But in debug I see that exit handler only works in nested procedure. Breakpoint at `DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION` not working.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have already caught this exception in your nested procedure and exception did not get thrown again. I think, you can remove exception handler from nested procedure or throw exception from it.